# Using Azure Site Recovery, creating a new environment (replica of production environment hosted on Azure)

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-site-recovery

just wondering if somebody or where I can find the source of information for using Azure Site Recovery to create exact copy of Azure production environment.

The reason is we have Active directory hosted in our production Azure VM, now we are trying to create copy of same AD in another environment (dev, test, integration). I am trying to use Azure site recovery to create another environment (VMs).

Any suggestion or source of information or any link if somebody has done this before.

Please note: this is not Azure Active directory, this is standard AD hosted on Azure VM

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't have actual experience, but Microsoft states that ASR can be used to make copy of VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-migrate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-quickstart